Android Studio permanently freezes when saving project
Couldn't udnerstand why suddenly Android Studio just freezes (can't click anything, nothing respond). In Task Manager it's not written that (proccess is not responding). Then I saw "Saving 'project'" each time it happens. I tried to restart Android Studio, clicked Ctrl+S to save project and same thing happened. I have 32Gb RAM, a lot of free space on all hard drives. It's also doesn't matter if emulator is running or not. Also tried to reboot PC. In Task Manager Android Studio consumes usual 4-6Gb of Memory. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Fixed with File -> Invalidate Caches
